# React multistep form with SessionStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm newish to React and have a multi step profile creation form. I've looked for a best use case for sessionStorage, but no one seems very passionate one way or the other. Currently I have the form being a main component:

```
render() {
switch (this.state.step) {
  case 2:
    return <Step nextStep={this.nextStep} prevStep={this.prevStep} /.
  case 3:
    return <Step nextStep={this.nextStep} prevStep={this.prevStep} />
  case 4:
    return <Step nextStep={this.nextStep} prevStep={this.prevStep} />
  case 5:
    return <Step nextStep={this.nextStep} prevStep={this.prevStep} />
  default:
    return <Step nextStep={this.nextStep} />
}
}
```

Each of these steps has multiple input fields and I was wondering if it was bad practice to store these values in sessionStorage in their component (or localstorage) rather than state or a redux Store and send them to the backend once all the fields have been collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. I'd say you need a very specific reason for saving it in session or local storage. That reason could be, that you need the form fields to persist, even if the user refreshes the page.

You can still use Redux along with local storage. You just use your local storage, to initialize the Redux state, and update the local storage using Redux actions.

So if you start with Redux, you can always add session- local storage later, if you decide you really need the inputs to be persistent between sessions.

Comment: It would be nice to be persistent over refreshes (although not needed). It's mainly that doing it through sessionStore is far quicker of a solution in this case (just add the values to the sessionStorage on each click of a next button), but if this introduces vulnerabilities/bad code, I will do the longer solution of using a redux store.

Comment: In the long run, I reckon that it wont be quicker. Using Redux - or something similar - is a (arguably) more structured and deterministic way of managing your application state. And it still allows you to extend it with e.g. local storage, etc., later if you find you really need it. If you just want quick and dirty, there's no reason to use session- localStorage at all. You could simply keep your state in a global object.

Comment: So the general answer is it's not bad persay, but it's definitely worth it to spend the time to do it right with redux from the start. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about order process as this is what I am doing in a project at the moment. Order process consists from steps with multiple forms.

- Whole Order state is stored somewhere (be it state in parent components, redux store, local storage, or combination of those).
- every step/form itself update only related portion of Order state - portion which form is interested in.
- on form submit, there is mechanism which validates form and allow, or disallows transition to next step (more on this bellow)

Transition from step A to B (or B to C, or any other) is managed with Finite State Machine. It holds current Order state (which tell what form should be rendered), definitions of steps and state transition across steps.

On transition attempt there is hooked invoked, if registered. Result of hook signals whether state machine should allow transition and update Order 
state. Hooks can be sync, or async as well...

Well, that's theory.

Finite State Machine of my choice https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine/tree/v3

Implementation is tied to project.